# Mono4Android Cant upload to emulator

Tags: mono, emulation

I am using Mono4Android and I have a huge problem.
After I compiled my programm(via run), I want to "upload it to a device".
So I am starting a Emulator and I wait, but the emulator is not listed a running, so I cannot test my program.
I am experiencing this problem on two computers, how to fix it?